# Deleted copy and assignment constructors in request_handler of the http server example

Tags: c++11, boost, boost-asio

Why are the copy and assignment constructors deleted in [request_handler in the ASIO http server example](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.62.0/example/cpp11/http/server/request_handler.hpp#L26-L27)? Here is the header to save the lookup:

```
class request_handler
{
public:
  request_handler(const request_handler&) = delete;
  request_handler& operator=(const request_handler&) = delete;

  /// Construct with a directory containing files to be served.
  explicit request_handler(const std::string& doc_root);

  /// Handle a request and produce a reply.
  void handle_request(const request& req, reply& rep);

private:
  /// The directory containing the files to be served.
  std::string doc_root_;

  /// Perform URL-decoding on a string. Returns false if the encoding was
  /// invalid.
  static bool url_decode(const std::string& in, std::string& out);
};
```

If anything, seems that the only field `doc_root_` can be made const and default constructors would do if needed? The code does not actually copy the handler in the published example. However, I am exploring the possibility in my code and it would be great to understand if I am missing something very basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense since copying `doc_root_` could result in extra memory allocation. That means for each new `connection`, it would copy the `request_handler` to the connection thereby doing a memory allocation (if SSO is not applicable on the `string` size ofcourse).

If I can avoid unnecessary allocations, I would definitely do that, more so in case where `request_handler` is not storing any per `connection` specific data.

NOTE: I am ready to move this as a comment if it doesn't answer the question entirely.

Comment: Do I miss where a `request_handler` might be copied? The `connection` constructor takes it by reference: https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.62.0/example/cpp11/http/server/connection.cpp#L21 . If it would be copied anywhere the current code with explicitly deleted copy constructor would not work.

I can understand if the deletion is a safeguard against an accidental future copying code, but that is all I can think of. Anything else?

Comment: Yes, in the code `request_handler` once constructed is always stored as a reference. If at all it was accidentally copied, the compiler would cry and fail because the copy and assignment functions are marked as deleted. Yes, deletion is a safeguard mechanism to tell the reader (and compiler) that the object cannot be copied and what I have answered is one of the reason for doing it. There are other reasons for doing the same, but this fits best with the code in question.